# How to upload image to database in php?

Tags: php, mysql

here i am trying to upload image to directory and add the path in database.
here i am first adding some product details and trying to upload the image to uploads directory and add the uploaded image path in database.

here is what i have done:

```
   <?php
    /* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
    server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "wan_products_box");

    // Check connection
    if($link === false){
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    // Escape user inputs for security
    $product_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['product_name']);
    $product_category = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['product_category']);
    $product_price = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['product_price']);
    $pro_url = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['pro_url']);
    $co_owners = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['co_owners']);


    // attempt insert query execution
    $sql = "INSERT INTO product_list (product_name, product_category, product_price,product_referrence_URL,product_co_owners) VALUES ('$product_name', '$product_category', '$product_price', '$pro_url', '$co_owners')";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
        echo "New product created.";
    } else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }

    //image upload code

    if($_POST)
    { 
    if($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
    else
    {
    if(file_exists("uploaded_images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
    {
    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    }
    else
    {  
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"uploaded_images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
    {
    $query_image = "INSERT INTO product_list (product_image_url) values ('".$_FILES['file']['name']."')";
    if(mysql_query($query_image))
    {
    echo "Stored in: " . "uploaded_images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'Unable to store';
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
```

this is my html form:

```
<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h4>Add new product</h4>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">        


            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="files/insert.php" role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="product_name">Product Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_name" id="product_name" placeholder="Iphone 5c" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Product Category</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">                            
                  <select class="btn-btn-primary form-control" name="product_category">
                    <option>Mobile</option>
                    <option>Television</option>
                    <option>Printer</option>
                    <option>Watch</option>
                    <option>Monitor</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="product-pic">Upload your profile picture</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">          
                  <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file" id="file" /> 
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="product_price">Product Price</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_price" id="product_price" placeholder="Rs.36,000" required>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pro_url">Reference URL</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="URL" class="form-control" name="pro_url" id="pro_url" placeholder="http://www.amazon.com" required>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="co_owners">Co-owners</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="btn-btn-primary form-control" name="co_owners">
                        <option>Select no. owners</option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                        <option>6</option>
                        <option>7</option>
                        <option>8</option>
                        <option>9</option>
                        <option>10</option>
                        <option>11</option>
                        <option>12</option>
                        <option>13</option>
                        <option>14</option>
                        <option>15</option>
                    </select>                      
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group">        
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add product</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>


      </div>
      </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
```

the data is inserted to database but the image upload part is not happening...
how can i do this? how can i modify the code to upload the image to database and add path to database?

when i run this the output i get is

```
New product created.
Notice: Undefined index: file in D:\xampp\htdocs\wan\files\insert.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: file in D:\xampp\htdocs\wan\files\insert.php on line 37

Notice: Undefined index: file in D:\xampp\htdocs\wan\files\insert.php on line 43

Notice: Undefined index: file in D:\xampp\htdocs\wan\files\insert.php on line
```

Comment: Can you show the form? Sounds like you don't have a file input named "file"

Comment: your form is failing, why? because... no valid enctype and/or missing name attribute

Comment: mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong in your code.

Firstly, your form is missing a valid enctype `enctype="multipart/form-data"` it is required when dealing with files.

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

You're also mixing MySQL APIs in your second query.

```
$query_image = "INSERT INTO product_list (product_image_url) values ('".$_FILES['file']['name']."')";
if(mysql_query($query_image))
```

- **So it will fail.**

Use the same method you used in your first query.

- **Those different APIs do not intermix.**

So change that to `if(mysqli_query($link, $query_image))`

Also add `or die(mysqli_error($link))` to `mysqli_query()` to check for errors.

Also make sure the folder has proper permissions to be written to.

Another thing, your `<select>`'s options have no values

```
<option>Select no. owners</option>
<option>1</option>
...
```

You need to add those

```
<option value="empty_value">Select no. owners</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
...
```

and do the same for the others.

Same thing for `<option>Mobile</option>`. There should be values for those too.

```
<option value="mobile">Mobile</option>
...
```

You will not get anything entered in your database for those.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the problems in HTML part like the lack of `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. There is a problem in your second Query and this is the cause of these errors:

```
$query_image = "INSERT INTO product_list (product_image_url) values ('".$_FILES['file']['name']."')";
```

You need to change this to an `UPDATE` query and update the already created row in database.

Also it is a better approach to use the row's index number for the image name.

Comment: You made a good point here. However, they're not using the right MySQL API for it, and as it stands and not seeing any accepted answer or comments for them, the OP's question is unclear.